# message read or not iphone

Tags: iphone, sms, message

how can i detect that received sms is read or not by user, i am using CTMessageCenter header also pleas help me..

and also tell me how can i put my application in background continuously....

Comment: This is two questions. They should be asked separately. Also you are not providing nearly enough information. Finally, there is no way to detect whether a user has read an SMS or not. In future, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

i think there is no method from which we can found that message is read or not in non jailbreak ...

Answer (score 0):

Ya you can read your incoming message and send also.In your main.m write this code and use three files:CoreTelephony.h,CTMessage.h,CTMessageCenter.h
One problem with this using this way you can't submit your app on app store.

```
static void callback(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, NSString* name, const void *object, NSDictionary* info) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Notification intercepted: %s\n", [name UTF8String]);
    if([name isEqualToString:@"kCTMessageReceivedNotification"] && info)
    {
        NSNumber* messageType = [info valueForKey:@"kCTMessageTypeKey"];
        if([messageType isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])
        {
            NSNumber* messageID = [info valueForKey:@"kCTMessageIdKey"];
            CTMessageCenter* mc = [CTMessageCenter sharedMessageCenter];
            CTMessage* msg = [mc incomingMessageWithId:[messageID intValue]];
            NSObject<CTMessageAddress>* phonenumber = [msg sender];

            NSString *senderNumber = (NSString*)[phonenumber canonicalFormat];
            NSString *sender = (NSString*)[phonenumber encodedString];
            CTMessagePart* msgPart = [[msg items] objectAtIndex:0]; //for single-part msgs
            NSData *smsData = [msgPart data];
            NSString *smsText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:smsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            fprintf(stderr, "SMS Message from %s / %s: \"%s\"\n",[senderNumber UTF8String],[sender UTF8String],[smsText UTF8String]);
        }
    }
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
    CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(ct, NULL, callback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);

    // Start the run loop. Now we'll receive notifications.
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
    NSLog(@"you are in main thread");
    [pool drain];
    printf("Unexpectedly back from CFRunLoopRun()!\n");
    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .
But is this possible by using public framework.

Comment: No this private and you can't upload your app on appstore,they will reject this.Apple doesn't provide to access private information in apps